# Ruby on Rails HTML Table not displaying correctly

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a simple Ruby on Rails index page using a table. My intention is to have the page include a HTML table that displays items from the model in each row. The model is called "Post", and it contains four attributes - Department, Professor, Course, and Title.

The problem is, the Table is displayed in a peculiar way as shown in the screenshot of the application at this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkE6M.png.

There is a huge chunk of nonsense texts displaying right above the table. The table itself is being rendered as intended, but I do not understand why the unnecessary text chunk is being displayed. There is no error message when I run the application. The rest of the application is displayed properly and functional.

The source code of the view of the page looks like this:

*index.html.erb*

```
<% provide(:title, 'All posts') %>
<h1>All posts</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Professor</th>
      <th>Course</th>
      <th>Title</th>
    </tr>s
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= @posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= post.department %></td>
        <td><%= post.professor %></td>
        <td><%= post.course %></td>
        <td><%= link_to post.title, post%></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Upon inspecting the source of the rendered page, I found out that the block of the problematic text is included within the table group. Below is a partial excerpt from the rendered HTML:

```
* .....more code above *

    <tr>
        <td>Quod sed ex fuga nemo.</td>
        <td>Isabel Douglas III</td>
        <td>Sint qui natus nesciunt.</td>
        <td><a href="/posts/2">Qui aperiam voluptas alias molestias nisi.</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Quod sed ex fuga nemo.</td>
        <td>Isabel Douglas III</td>
        <td>Sint qui natus nesciunt.</td>
        <td><a href="/posts/1">Qui aperiam voluptas alias molestias nisi.</a></td>
    </tr>
[#&lt;Post id: 60, department: &quot;Consequatur voluptatem.&quot;, professor: &quot;Humberto Wisozk&quot;, course: &quot;Suscipit rerum possimus culpa aut et.&quot;, content: &quot;Beatae minima aut est eos.&quot;, user_id: 6, created_at: &quot;2014-01-14 20:15:11&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2014-01-14 20:15:11&quot;, title: &quot;Sed quia.&quot;&gt;, #&lt;Post id: 59, department: &quot;Consequatur voluptatem.&quot;, professor: &quot;Humberto Wisozk&quot;, course: &quot;Suscipit rerum possimus culpa aut et.&quot;, content: &quot;Beatae minima aut est eos.&quot;, user_id: 5, created_at: &quot;2014-01-14 20:15:11&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2014-01-14 20:15:11&quot;, title: &quot;Sed quia.&quot;&gt;, #&lt;Post id: 58, department: &quot;Consequatur voluptatem.&quot;, professor: &quot;Humberto Wisozk&quot;, course: &quot;Suscipit rerum possimus culpa aut et.&quot;, content: &quot;Beatae minima aut est eos.&quot;, user_id: 4, created_at: &quot;2014-01-14 20:15:11&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2014-01-14 20:15:11&quot;, title: &quot;Sed quia.&quot;&gt;, #&lt;Post id: 57, department: &quot;Consequatur voluptatem.&quot;, professor: &quot;Humberto Wisozk&quot;, course: &quot;Suscipit rerum possimus culpa aut et.&quot;, content: &quot;Beatae minima aut est eos.&quot;, user_id: 3, created_at: &quot;2014-01-14 20:15:11&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2014-01-14 20:15:11&quot;, title: &quot;Sed quia.&quot;&gt;, #&lt;Post id: 56, department: &quot;Consequatur voluptatem.&quot;, professor: &quot;Humberto Wisozk&quot;, course: &quot;Suscipit rerum possimus culpa aut et.&quot;, content: &quot;Beatae minima aut est eos.&quot;, user_id: 2, created_at: &quot;2014-01-14 20:15:11&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2014-01-14 20:15:11&quot;, title: &quot;Sed quia.&quot;&gt;, #&lt;]  </tbody>
</table>

* more code below.... *
```

Below is the Gemfile used for the application:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem "simple_form"
gem 'faker', '1.1.2' # allow us to make sample users
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4' # pagination method
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9' # configures will_paginate to use Bootstrap's style

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the `=` in `<%= @posts.each do |post| %>`.

`array.each{}` returns the array, for chaining

Comment: ^-- What he said. The `<%=` ERb tag displays the output of the call. The `<%` tag does not.